# Django Custom Queryset filters

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, generator-expression

Is there, in Django, a standard way to write complex, custom filters for QuerySets?

Just as I can write

```
MyClass.objects.all().filter(field=val)
```

I'd like to do something like this :

```
MyClass.objects.all().filter(customFilter)
```

I could use a generator expression

```
(x for x in MyClass.objects.all() if customFilter(x))
```

but that would lose the chainability and whatever other functions the QuerySets provide.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you may need custom [managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

Comment: I guess I do need this. But it looks awfully complicated compared to just being able to pass a filter function in on the fly.

Comment: It's not very complicated, and it's a good practice to make custom managers, especially if you plan on caching stuff from db etc.

Answer (score 16):

The recommendation to start using manager methods is a good one, but to answer your question more directly: yes, use [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).  For example:

```
from django.db.models import Q

complexQuery = Q(name__startswith='Xa') | ~Q(birthdate__year=2000)

MyModel.objects.filter(complexQuery)
```

Q objects can be combined with | (OR), & (AND), and ~ (NOT).