# Can Django models have shortcut properties?

Tags: django, django-models

Is there a way that I can take a model, define a field equivalent and use that to filter on?

Example Model:

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, db_column='company_uuid')
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('Account No'))
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    notes = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'manufacturer'
```

Could I then proceed to add something like this on the model:

```
self.field(name, self.company.name)
```

and then be able to do:

```
Manufacturer.objects.filter(name="Davies")
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple case, you would just do:

```
Manufacturer.objects.filter(company__name='Davies')
```

If you want to define a custom filter, it looks like the best way to do this is to set a custom manager on your model as described here:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

I have not actually done this, but if you define a manager for your model, you should be able to do one of the following:

- Override the `filter` method, then you should be able to modify `kwargs` as necessary to replace your aliases with your long ugly join
- Define a new method like `my_filter` that applies the filtering you want

A related SO question: [Django Custom Queryset filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672182/django-custom-queryset-filters)

Comment: I want to simplify the interface to a model, this example is contrived. the real Model involves a much longer chaining of joins and we're using it almost constantly. This is causing most of our views to contain this long string and it's pretty much unreadable. Our problem domain is very complicated to model.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect this.